# Tips for dealing with a temporary change request in an MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, version-control, architecture, change-management

I am working on an application, for which a temporary change request has come in to a given feature.  Specifically, the business currently only wants to manage a Physical address for a given customer, and wants us to remove the option to add a mailing address.

This feature will most likely need to be re-introduced in the future, so, I am wondering what the best way to handle the removal would be for now.  Having additional properties on the ViewModel is not necessarily a problem, but, it's messy.  And there is even more of a problem when it comes to the View itself.  We need to remove the UI elements, but, we need to make it easy to bring it back in the future.

So...do I comment out the unneeded code bits?  This is the simplest approach, but, it's messy.

Do I create a new View and ViewModel?  If so, where is the appropriate place to store the original for safe-keeping?  Our application is under source control (SVN), so, we could theoretically come back to this revision, but, it seems like overkill for such a small change.

Has anyone else run into a similar situation?  Any recommendation on how to best handle this?

Answer (score 1):

> So...do I comment out the unneeded code bits?

No, that would be very messy. That's what version control is intended to do.

> Do I create a new View and ViewModel?

Yes, replace the original.

> If so, where is the appropriate place to store the original for safe-keeping?

Version control.

> Our application is under source control (SVN), so, we could theoretically come back to this revision, but, it seems like overkill for such a small change.

overkill? No. That's what VCS do best => they keep revision history. Also you might consider creating a label so that you can easily come back later.

Comment: Your quick answers confirm my thought that this is the best way to do it, but, I still feel very hesitant.  In SVN, the closest I can get to a label is a Tag, and using a Tag for this purpose doesn't fit within our development process (we tag versions, in the case that we need to go back to branch for a bug fix).

Answer (score 0):

What view engine? Actually, that may or may not matter.

From a standpoint of "I may need this going forward", I would consider moving the UI bits that are going away for now and may reappear in an MVC user control. It is less "messy" than commenting out code all over the place. You can then exclude it for now.

As for the ViewModel? There are a couple of possibilities. The short pole is certainly adding the bits to the ViewModel, even if not used, but that means you are spinning up data that is not in use with no clear timeframe for when it will be used. But you can always create a derived class when you need the extra information and have the user control cast the view model to the derived class (co-variance and contra-variance are your friends) when you start using it, making code changes rather minor when the business "comes to its senses".

Comment: The View engine is Razor, but, I agree, it really shouldn't matter. I have decided to go with a similar approach, deriving my customized ViewModel from the base, and building the view from composable partial views, so that adding this piece back, when it is inevitability requested, will be a simple matter